Finding the area between two parabolas with orthogonal axes.
I have two equations: $y=x^2+1$ and $x=(y-2)^2-1$. How would I find the area between these two curves?
Should I rewrite one of the equations in terms of the other? For instance, rearranging $x=(y-2)^2-1$ in terms of $y$. Furthermore, from what I am calculating, there are two separate regions that make up the area between. So, would this call for two different integral expressions in order to determine the total area?

There are actually $3$ distinct bounded regions; see this plot. Do you know which one you're supposed to determine?

@user170231 The two leftmost ones.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity Apologies, it was a typo. I have fixed it now.


Should I rewrite one of the equations in terms of the other?

Yes, this is standard for a problem like this. Choosing to integrate w.r.t. $x$, we consider the curves
$$\begin{cases}y_b=x^2+1 \\ y_o=2-\sqrt{x+1} \end{cases}$$
where the second equation corresponds to the bottom half of the orange parabola $y_o$.


would this call for two different integral expressions

Technically, no. First, confirm that the curves intersect at $x\in\{-1,0\}$ (I leave finding the third intersection to you). The area of the two "lobes" bounded above by $y_b$, then later $y_o$, can be computed with the definite integral,
$$\int_{-1}^0 \left\lvert y_b - y_o \right\rvert \, dx$$
Plot of the integrand:

You can then invoke the definition of absolute value to split up the integral at the omitted intersection, expanding it as
$$\int_{-1}^? (y_b-y_o) \, dx + \int_?^0 (y_o-y_b) \, dx$$
but you need only compute one antiderivative, since this expression can be re-condensed to
$$\left\{\int_{-1}^? + \int_0^?\right\} (y_b-y_o) \, dx$$
